# ASP.NET Javascript Not being loaded when ASP Page has URL Mapping

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, web

I'm trying to retrieve the ID of an employee and show them in my details page by retrieving the Employee ID from the URL using Page Mapping in ASP.NET:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "employee/{id}", "~/details.aspx");
```

Such that the URL will be:

> www.myexamplewebsite.com/employee/7937822353

The problem is, the Javascript files don't get loaded and the console is full of my javascript errors. I get a 404 error in my JS scrips as well. The page can't find any JS file when mapped. Why is this happening when I map the URL? This does not happen if the URL is www.myexamplewebsite.com/7937822353.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is how my JS files are referenced:

```
 <script src="js/chatbar/rightside.js"> </script>
```

Comment: can you provide the markup from your view that show how the JS is referenced.  This is likely a relative path issue.

Comment: @GlennFerrie Edited it in :)

Comment: that's great. so, when you see the 404 in the Browser Tools, what is the full URL that it is targeting and what is the actual path to the JS?

Comment: having `myexamplewebsite.com/employee` is not a subdomain. That's a different concept. A subdomain is like `mobile.myexamplewebsite.com`.

Comment: @GlennFerrie What do you mean full URL mate? Is this the one? www.myexamplewebsite.com/js/chatbar/rightside.js

Comment: What i was driving at is this.  Your JS file lives somewhere in your site and the browser is misinterpreting the relative path you referenced,  The Response from the HTTP request that yielded a 404 error should show the full URL that represents where it "thinks" your JS file is.  When you compare that to where you JS file actually is, you can get closer to resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is relative, and it's from the perspective of the client side URL. So when you change the page route to have the page appear to be served from a `/employee` subdirectory, the correct relative path to your scripts changes. So it's looking for the scripts at `/employee/js/charbar/rightside.js`. You could change those relative paths (to something like `../js/chartbar/rightside.js`), but you might run into a problem later if you change the routing again.

So instead, it's best to make the reference *application root relative*.

```
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/chatbar/rightside.js")%>'></script>
```

Comment: The PageMethods don't get loaded when I add this mate.  PageMethods.loaddetails(onSuccess, onFailure); doesn't work :/

Comment: @Earthling That sounds like a separate issue.